# recursive setTimeout pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

While reading an article on [Long Polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery) I got little confused between following two flavors of `setInterval`

1 -

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
    }, dataType: "json"});
}, 30000);
```

2-

```
(function poll() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data) {
            sales.setValue(data.value);
       }, dataType: "json", complete: poll });
    }, 30000);
})();
```

As per blog it says - About second snippet,

> So, this pattern doesn't guarantee execution on a fixed interval per
>   se. But, **it does guarantee that the previous interval has completed
>   before the next interval is called**.

Why second snippet guarantee that the previous interval has completed?

I know about first (Event loops) but little confused about second snippet.

Comment: _Why second snippet guarantee that the previous interval has completed?_, it guarantees that previous **AJAX** is completed

Comment: @Tushar thats the question actually. Why not first can guarantee the same?

Comment: What if the AJAX took time more than `30000`ms to complete

Comment: In case of second approach, setTimeout only gets called once first time. And it gets called again in the callback of ajax. So it guarantees that the ajax call is complete before the second time execution starts. While in case of first approach, regardless of ajax result, setInterval keeps calling function at regular interval. It does not care whether the call back arrives as a result of previous execution. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why second snippet guarantee that the previous interval has completed?

At first example `$.ajax()` is called at an interval, whether or not previous `$.ajax()` call completes.

At second example `poll` is not called again until `complete` function of `$.ajax()`.